# how to change background color of textarea and textbox - javascript

Tags: textarea

I'm trying to change the background color of the textarea and text box. 
All this must be done when the user presses the button click, it activates a function that changes the color of the two components at random. 
The code I've written does not work, could you help me?

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="text"></textarea><br/>
<input type="text" id="c"><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="as()" value="clicca">
</body>

<script>

function as()
{

var t = document.getElementById('text');
var c = document.getElementById('c');

t.style="color: red; background-color: lightyellow"

}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: what result do you get when you run it ?

Comment: t.css("background-color","red")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the backgroundColor directly with JavaScript:

```
t.style.backgroundColor='blue';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 t.css("background-color","red")
```